# transform: rotateY() making element disappear

Tags: css

I am trying to apply a simple `transform: rotateY(90deg)` on an div but it's (the div) disappearing as a result, dev tools is not throwing any error on that line, any suggestions or anything I might be missing?

Comment: When you rotate an element in Y axis by 90 degree it will disappear because the element has no depth (for want of a better word). Take a piece of paper, keep it in front of your eye, rotate it by 90 degree along Y axis and see what happens :)

Comment: Does it only disappear from viewport or does it also disappear from DOM? Which browser do you use?

Comment: it's still in the dom, with nothing in its place just blank space

Comment: @harry thanks that was it exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when you rotate something on the Y axis by 90 degrees it has spun so that it's essentially facing a different direction. In the below example I've added a transition to show how the element changes over time (hover over it):

```css
figure {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 100px;
}

div:hover figure {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure></figure>
</div>
```

As our viewport looks directly onto the element and features no depth, it appears that the element has disappeared altogether.

If we do add some depth, it's easier to visualise what's happening:

[image: Example]

The cube on the left is our pre-transform cube and the cube on the right is our cube after it's had `rotateY(90deg)` applied to it. As we have no depth at all and we're looking at our element front on, we can't see anything when it gets rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: How can we solve this problem?